# AngularJs 1.4.8 remove hash from url

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I'm practising a demo application using AngularJs 1.4.8 with backend as core php. Im using linux os. My app files reside inside, var/www/demo/ang/ directory. What I need is, to remove the **"#"** hash from the url. I approached many examples from internet but the only final result Im getting is that nothing being displayed in the browser. Most of the approaches say to set

```
<head>
    <base href="/" />
</head>
```

or

```
<head>
    <base href="/var/www/demo/ang/" />
</head>
```

---

```
app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider)
{

   $routeProvider
   .when('/', {
       templateUrl : 'index.html',
       controller : indexController
   })
   .when('/about', {
       templateUrl : 'about.html',
       controller : aboutController
   });
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

});
```

or

```
app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider)
{

    $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl : 'index.html',
        controller : indexController
    })
    .when('/about', {
        templateUrl : 'about.html',
        controller : aboutController
    });
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(
            {
               enabled:true, 
               requireBase: false
            });
});
```

Even tried this  **$locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');** . I know that somewhere I'm doing a mistake or forgot to add something. Kindly help me to go through this

**UPDATED:** **Answer Found**
https://www.formget.com/angularjs-remove-hashtag/

I made two mistakes

One mistake is that, I set the `<base href=""/>` as absolute path rather than the relative path of the url. Hence provide the relative path `http://www.siteame.com/` or `http://localhost/path/to/angularjs_dir/`

Second mistake is that, I named the main file which includes all the scripts, ng-view etc.., as some name other than index.html. Hence provide the base file name as index.html.

Rest of this all others were correct.

Comment: Don't remove # on local, there's no point of doing these things at local, 
But with all these things you need to write some rewrite rules at the server. So if you have any server, what it is? i.e. AWS, nginx, tomcat etc

Comment: Ok. I will try and let you know

Comment: No improvement . I have provided an htaccess file to redirect the url to index.html file of the angular app, but still it does not show any content